# How to store MySql query result in variable in MyBatis

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mybatis

I have pretty big query. It looks like this:

```
select * from
(
    select [custom columns]
    from table
    where id in
    (
      select id 
      from table2
      where pr_id in
      ( 
        select id 
        from table3
        where id = #{id}
      ) and ac_id != #{acId}
    ) and [some_column1] like #{pattern}

    union

    select [custom columns2]
    from table
    where id in
    (
      select id 
      from table2
      where pr_id in
      ( 
        select id 
        from table3
        where id = #{id}
     ) and ac_id != #{acId}
    ) and [some_column2] like #{pattern}

    union

    .....
)
```

... and two more unions

All I want to do is to query two inner queries which start with select id from table2 into some variable first and after that use this query result in union queries.

I tried something like this

```
SET @var1 = (
  select id 
      from table2
      where pr_id in
      ( 
        select id 
        from table3
        where id = #{id}
      ) and ac_id != #{acId}
)

select * from
(
    select [custom columns]
    from table
    where id in
    (select @var1)
    and [some_column1] like #{pattern}

    union

    ....
)
```

but mybatis provided me with an error. Is there way to do what I need?

The error is following:

```
Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from
    (
      select firstname, lastname, organization, email, null ' at line 11
```

select firstname, lastname, organization, email, null ' at line 11 is [custom columns]

full [custom columns] look like this:

```
select firstname, lastname, organization, email, null 'applicationId', null 'applicationName', (locate(_ascii #{value}, convert(email using ascii)) - 1) 'index', length(#{value}) 'length', 'EMAIL' as 'type'
```

Answer (score 0):

What might work better instead of dealing with variables is to include SQL fragments in your query.  In your mapping file:

```
<sql id="var1">
    select id from table2 
    where pr_id in (...) and ac_id != #{ac_id}
</sql>
```

Now you can include this fragment anywhere in your SQL:

```
<select id="big_select">
    select * from (
        select [cols] from table where id in (
        <include refid="var1"/>
        ) and [col] like #{pattern}
   union
   ...etc...
```

You may also want to look at the SQL `WITH` clause, which you might also use to simplify your query.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I thought about such solutions, but I suppose that it will decrease query size visually only. If I got everything right it will query <sql></sql> part four times. I wanted to query it once and use result.